# This version of mysql2 (0.2.18) isn't compatible with Rails 3.1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Any help would be greatly appreciated, when I run the "generate model" command I get the following message:

```
 WARNING: This version of mysql2 (0.2.18) isn't compatible with Rails 3.1 as the ActiveRecord adapter was pulled into Rails itself.
 WARNING: Please use the 0.3.x (or greater) releases if you plan on using it in Rails >= 3.1.x
```

Is there a way to update the mysql2 version so it works with rails 3.1? or perhaps i could downgrade rails from 3.1 to 3.0?

Comment: Have you tried [updating the mysql2 gem](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/10#page40) ?  It would seem going forward will prove a better strategy over the long haul.

Answer (score 10):

You need to run

```
gem update mysql2
```

or add

```
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11"
```

to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`

Comment: you should click the green checkmark to assign credit if it worked

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem even after upgrading. It kept refusing to use 0.3.11 and defaulted back to the earlier version.

Finally figured out that in the Gemfile I had it written "< 0.3" instead of "> 0.3".

Kind of obscure (and dumb), but maybe it'll help someone.